# Jenkins 2 pipeline + maven release

Tags: jenkins, maven-release-plugin, jenkins-workflow

As I've seen The jenkins maven release plugin does not works with pipeline job.
What is the preferred way to releasing with pipeline? Should I use the maven release plugin?

thanks, for yiur answer.

Answer (score 1):

We use the maven-release-plugin for maven (not jenkins) with Pipeline.  It works fine using the sh or bat steps.

One word of caution, when specifying the password for the plugin, special characters will be processed by the shell which can create issues.  In order to get around this, I use the writeFile step to write the command-line to a file then use a python script to perform a fork/exec to avoid shell processing.